# How can I cast a Polars DataFrame to string

Tags: python, pandas, python-polars

How do I stringify a small ***df.head*** result.

I have the following code:

```
df.head(row_amount).to_pandas().to_string()
```

I normally print out 2 or 3 rows but I need it in a string. I solved it like above by transforming it to pandas first. I have also solved it by Output buffering the print, but those are crazy solutions.

Is there an easier way to stringify the df?

Comment: What kind of output do you need? Does `str(df.head())` suffice? There's also `df.head().to_init_repr()` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Polars has quite a few [Config](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/config.html) options that will let you customize how `str(df)` will behave.

To get the output closest to pandas `.to_string()` then you'd want to get rid of the dtype, shape, and borders.

```
pl.Config.set_tbl_hide_dataframe_shape(True)
pl.Config.set_tbl_formatting('NOTHING')
pl.Config.set_tbl_hide_column_data_types(True)
mystr=str(df.head(2))
print(mystr)
 a           b     c  d    
 2023-06-01  null  4  null 
 2023-06-01  null  5  null
```

if you want to get back to "normal" after that then you can

```
pl.Config.restore_defaults()
```

or if your normal is already otherwise configured then you can save and load your config state too.